# how to display image from file system

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I want to display images from file system, which will dynamically change by query.

for example: employee_id = 1001 then show image C:\images\emp_1001.jpg

I want to set the file path from the query.

I am using Reports 6i.

Regards:

Comment: Set the property "Read from file" to Yes for the item in the datemodel, and additionally set the filetype to "Image" (also in the properties of the item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property "Read from file" to Yes for the item in the datemodel, and additionally set the filetype to "Image" (also in the properties of the item)